# Replacing Apache2 for Varnish as reverse proxy

Tags: apache2, varnish, varnish-vcl, proxypass

I'm having some troubles replacing a Apache2 reverse proxy rule for a Varnish ACL.

The apache rule is:

```
<Location /MySite>
        ProxyPass       http://192.168.0.123/OtherSite
</Location>
```

My Varnish ACL:

```
if (req.url ~ "^/(?i)MySite") {
    set req.backend = myhost; # 192.168.0.123
    set bereq.url = regsub(req.url, "^/(?i)MySite", "/OtherSite");
    return (pipe);
}
```

This is causing the URL on the client side to change to "/OtherSite", which I do not want to happen. On this scenario, when user enters http://www.myhost.com/MySite, the response is redirecting the user's browser to http://www.myhost.com/OtherSite. I want this "redirection" to happen only on varnish back-end request, having the same behavior as Apache's ProxyPass.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you test by removing the line "return (pipe)" ?

Comment: Yes, it falls on a lookup statement and the same thing occurs.

Comment: We need more details, can you pastebin a varnishlog of your scenario?